# How to get rid of mosquitos in swimming pool standing water

Tags: pool, mosquitoes

We have an above ground pool with about 6 inches of water that does not drain. The drain is located above the bottom, to keep water in it and weigh down the pool during the off season.

However, the still warm water is the perfect breeding ground for mosquitos. This is a problem during the advent of warmer weather, before the pool is used.

[image]

It is a salt water system, and the pumps & chlorinator obviously cannot be operated with the water drained to this level. Once the pool is operational in the hot season, the conditioning and filtering prevent this mosquito problem. So this is really only a problem when the Spring weather is warm enough for breeding, but prior to starting the pool for the Summer.

Before I start-up the pool to fill it, I drain the water with a sump or water feature pump and then wet-vac it dry. This is something I do once at the beginning of the season, and takes a few hours of work. As measure to prevent mosquitos it would not be so good, since the bottom will fill with every rainfall and I'd have to start over.

What can I do to prevent mosquitos breeding until I start-up the pool for the season?

Comment: Fit a domed cover and then keep it dry.

Comment: Add a little soap to the water, and the larvae cannot stay at the top to breathe or is it oil? vegetable or other??

Comment: @Jack it is oil

Comment: @Jack I second this. We throw a few drops of oil into a stash of old tires to keep mosquitoes down. I was told the larvae cannot emerge/breathe with the skim of oil on top.

Comment: Don't put soap or oil in your pool - that will just make a colossal mess that will require a ton of water to wash out and clean before you can fill it and start filtering.

Comment: you can also get a portable sump pump or long hose attached to a wet dry vac and get rid of the water

Comment: @NKCampbell, yes but it will refill at the next rainfall. I use a pump to drain it when starting the pool each season.

Comment: get a cover to keep it from the rain?

Comment: @NKCampbell it's large, no soft cover will be able to keep rain out without collapsing. Keeping it dry is not an option for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First point : **Chemical warfare is the tool of last resort for pool maintenance.**

Sometimes you end up in a crisis and you need to deal with it, but if you look after the pool correctly it should be absolutely unnecessary.  Chemicals are a double-edged sword.  They can get you out of a mess, but they come with headaches of their own.  If you can avoid letting the pool get this bad in the first place it's altogether the better option.

> This is a problem during the advent of warmer weather, before the pool is used.

The error here is to think of filling the pool as something you do when you want to swim.  If a pool is of such a size that it cannot be drained of water then it is something you need to care for year-round, and treating the water is as much for the pool's sake as it is for yours.  If the pool requires some water to remain in it all year around then it requires maintenance all year around.

Once the water temperature rises above 10C(50F), the water becomes a breeding ground for insects, algae, etc.  **You need to fill the pool and start treating the water when this happens - not simply when you want to swim**. The pool needs to be opened sooner - once the water is chlorinated and is being filtered with the pump it's fine.  So you need to start doing that *before* biology has a chance to take over.

If you really don't want to open the pool when the temperature starts rising, you need to otherwise keep it covered and chlorinated.  The cover will prevent the sun from burning off the chlorine, but you will need to monitor the chlorine levels or algae begins to grow, and since this is a lot easier to do and manage with the pool filled and circulating daily it just makes more sense to open the pool and start treating it once the weather becomes favourable for algal growth and insect infestation.

In the long run, this saves you on chemicals, cost, and nasty cleanup time (scrubbing out algae and slime) and it increases the usable life of your pool.

> Before I start-up the pool to fill it, I drain the water with a sump or water feature pump and then wet-vac it dry, but obviously this would only be good until the next rainfall.

If you open the pool earlier, before it grows into pond scum, you can keep that water from last year, for example, and save yourself the trouble of scrubbing all of that filth out.  Same thing in the fall - keep the pool open a few weeks later, until the water temperature drops below (10C/50F) and give the leftovers a good shock before you close up. You can have clear, clean water sitting in the pool over winter and ready to go come spring.

In colder temperatures when the pool is not getting much use you don't need much circulation to keep the water clear - a minimum of chlorine and a few hours of circulation is all you need.  It will depend on the size of pool and pump, but whatever your pump's throughput is you can calculate how long it takes to circulate the full pool volume.  As long as you run about a pool's volume through the filter per day that's plenty.  A few hours is usually enough.  Use a timer.

The energy and chemicals costs of keeping the pool open longer are small compared to the work they save you in having to un-swamp and hard shock the thing every season.  My pool has been open for the past seven weeks and I've spent perhaps $20 of electricity and used 2kg of chlorine (in-ground, 80,000L (20,000 gallon)) - for a smaller above-ground pool your costs will be even less.

You'll want to be very careful (ie: don't do it!) about adding additional chemicals to your pool. Soaps, oils, insecticides, metallic algecides, and other additives are not good for the pool, the pump, filter, or your chlorinator.  If you add these things to the still water, you again have a big cleanup job to get all of that stuff out of there before you start up the pump and filter.  If you don't clean it, it will end up in your filter and can cause damage to the pump or the other equipment.

Comment: Also once temperature is low, a few hours of filtration a day is more than enough (use a timer). The amount of chemicals needed is also much less. It really is easier to run the system as long as the water is not frozen.

Comment: @Olivier Yes, absolutely.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Running the pump requires keeping the pool filled, which goes against manufacturer's recommendation for winter/freezing. Conditioning the 6in over winter is problematic because it can rain as much and flush it within a month. Conditioning the 6in before warm weather, or simply starting the pool early are workable options.

Comment: @P2000 Yes, I'm not suggesting running the pump with ice in the pool, obviously.  You fill and circulate when the water is going to be warmer than 10C (50F).  You close likewise in the fall.  10C(50F) is above freezing, so the water will be perfectly liquid.  Over winter you leave the 6" in the pool and cover it.  Very little will grow in the pool without treatment or circulation if the water is below 10C.

Comment: Ok, so ultimately you are suggesting to start the pool at about 10C. That's not a bad idea for next year. I prefer that over chemicals. Indeed, the pump won't need to run as much until the hot summer days.

Comment: @P2000 Yes, exactly.  You just need a little bit of run time and chlorine to keep the pool clear in the cooler spring and fall.  Way easier than leaving it too late, or closing too early, and then having to muck out the bog of eternal stench every year.

Comment: @P2000 If you're interested in learning a bit more about pool maintenance, this place is a great resource [Trouble Free Pool](https://www.troublefreepool.com/blog/)

Comment: Yes I like that one a lot. Above ground salt water is relatively new (well, it was when I started)  and I didn't recall anything there about mosquitos. So I think the info you and others provide here are specifically applicable, and useful for anyone with a similar set-up.

Comment: @P2000 Indeed, and not just mosquitoes - I see in your photo that there's a lot of algae growth in there also.  Opening earlier solves both problems.

Comment: I went with this solution: start the pool early (although we had warm days, it's still early here). Added benefit: during cleaning the sun doesn't cake on the algae and leaves. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @P2000 Glad it worked out.  My pool has been open since Apr. 10th and the water has been clean and clear the whole time - it really makes life easier!  I think this week is probably the first time that the pool is now warm enough to properly swim in.  Secondary benefit is that you can look out your window and see a nice blue pool instead of a festering pit or even just a cover.

Answer (score 17):

Mosquito Dunks are a doughnut shaped product for exactly your problem. They contain a bacterium toxic to mosquito larva but not toxic to humans, pets or birds. They will only kill larva.

Any adult mosquito travelling by will still be available to bite you. You might also check out designs for bat or bird houses to encourage some natural predation.

Comment: AKA ; BT............

Comment: Natural predation would be great *during* the season. How many bats or birds would you need? Of course "it depends", but for around the pool, are we talking 1, 10, 100? Nice tip. I'll first try the BT/Dunk for the standing water.

Comment: We use BT, it works well. I buy it in powder form, mix in with water, and spray the pool. 5 minutes every week, no mosquitoes.

Comment: @bobflux do you do that for a full pool or do you have a similar "bottom 6in" problem? How much do you use?

Comment: Half-full pool, depends on how much it rained. I use the amount it says on the can, about one tablespoon powder in the sprayer. BT is nice because it's not toxic to humans, fish, etc, only kills larva. But you got to do it every week. I bought a 500 grams can years ago, it lasts forever.

Comment: @bobflux "BT"? What's that?

Comment: It's a [bacteria toxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacillus_thuringiensis) that kills larva and caterpillars. Got famous when Monsanto put the gene for it in their Bt corn.

Comment: After some more reading based on this answer, I'd like to add that we need BT (as mentioned here), not BTK. Mosquito Dunks contain BT (bacillus thuringensis). But note: "More than 20 varieties of Bt exist. The "kurstaki" variety (Btk) is used to control caterpillars."

Answer (score 15):

**Copper metal.**

Copper discourages mosquito larvae.  I used to think that the copper was directly toxic to the larvae but experiments showed this was not so - adding copper (as metal; a piece of pipe) to a fish tank where larvae were already living did not kill them.

Copper in standing water however reduces algae growth and algae is what the mosquito larvae eat.  An outdoor fishtank with a piece of copper pipe in it from the start harbors few larvae or algae.

I keep a coil of thin copper pipe and put it in the aquarium if the water gets green.  It works fast.  If I leave it more than a couple of days the fish stop eating but they perk up a day or 2 after it is out.

---

**Goldfish**

The other option is goldfish.  I tried this at a different year from the copper experiments.  I had a fish aquarium outside which had filled with rain and then with mosquito larvae and it seemed a shame to waste them.  Two 8 cent goldfish made short work of those larvae and then sustained themselves on whatever else fell in the water over the rest of the summer.  Two goldfish would be cheaper than a piece of copper if you don't have any pipe scraps.  I used 2 because just 1 seemed lonely.

For efficiency the copper works fine and you can take it out and use it year after year.  The goldfish were more fun.

Comment: I have an ornamental pond right next to the house. We have a local kind of fish called Bitterling, which are brown, so the cat can't see them. These fish love larvae. We don't have any in the pond. If there are larvae in e.g. the rain barrel, I scoop them out with a bucket and slop them into the pond, and the fish go into a feeding frenzy.

Comment: That's a lovely idea: Turn the pool into a goldfish pond in the off-season! Add some algae eaters and you are all good.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick, copper is toxic to pretty much anything from algae to humans. But a piece of copper metal will only very slowly release toxic copper ions, so there's fair chance that the resulting concentration simply isn't high enough to kill the larvae. If you added some copper sulphate to the water, the larvae would promptly go belly up. (The water wouldn't likely be safe for humans afterwards, so don't.)

Comment: Copper is even more toxic to fish than it is to most other things. Not surprised there is enough to bother fish before mosquito larva even notice it.

Comment: The chlorinator also contains a block of copper which keeps the pool free of algae. But of course this only works in season, when the pump is running. What you write is interesting, as it suggests the larvae thrive as a result of the booming algae. I'd have to try this starting at the *end* of the season, before the bottom turns green. Do goldfish attract wildlife? That would be a concern...

Comment: @P2000 - a big pond with big fish will have fish eating birds visit.  You can give them something to hide in like a flower pot or cinder block.  In the rainwater aquaria I never had anything eat my little 8 cent outside goldfish.   Except one time with a giant beetle larva I did not realize had ridden in with some pond weeds I added.

Comment: @P2000 - the copper will ungreen it pretty fast.  The fish will not ungreen it but will demosquito it even faster.

Comment: +1 for "I used 2 because just 1 seemed lonely.". Priceless.

Comment: Make sure your goldfish are compatible with your saltwater pool. It'd be a shame to waste those 8¢ goldfish...

Comment: My beautiful shubunkin and my cute goldfish were eaten by the neighbour's new cat. OK, I can live with brown Bitterling. I will get new pretty fish when either that cat dies or I find a way to keep cats away that still allows little birds to drink and bathe. To ward off herons we have two bronze sculptures, because herons do not like company. (We got two because one would be lonely.)

Answer (score 11):

> It is a salt water system, and the pumps & chlorinator obviously cannot be operated with the water drained to this level.

Just in case you're not aware, the salt water isn't what keeps your pool clean. The chlorinator converts the salt to chlorine. You've got two problems there, in that the green stuff is algae (which is is a pain to rid yourself of once it gets going strong).

Go buy some liquid chlorine (or basic un-enhanced bleach) and start shocking the tar out of that standing water *until it is no longer green*. At that point, the mosquito problem will be gone as well. Liquid bleach plays nice with salt systems, just be aware that after this is done, you might need to check the pH levels before refilling the pool (as this will probably make the remaining water acidic).

Something to consider for the off-season would be a pool tablet float. It will add some chlorine slowly to the standing water when your pump isn't running.

Comment: Yes, chemically treating and winterizing the bottom 6in is a good idea. However, the winter rain will flush it almost monthly, so I'd have to see what would be a good release rate, or perhaps add the chlorine early spring when it's warmer but does not rain as much anymore.

Comment: @P2000 The key is to take note when the daylight gets long enough to warm the water and start the serious stuff then (I'd start the tablet float as soon as coat weather is done). Every time I've let my pool get that green, it takes a ton of effort to get it back to normal. Mosquitos are seriously the least of your problems here.

Comment: Depends on your climate, but mosquitos are only a problem in summer here.

Answer (score 3):

Any standing water attracts mosquitos so the first step is to drain all water. If draining is difficult, add BT ( bacillus thuringensis ) , a common insecticide that only affects insects. Other insecticide could be used but may require reapplication, and may require removal before swimming.

Comment: BT might be the only solution. Draining is not possible because of height of drains and I believe intentionally sp for the reasons mentioned in the question (weighing down). Removal should be no problem since pool is vacuumed and scrubbed before fill.

Comment: Draining _is_ possible. I'd use a sump pump or a wet-dry vac. No way I'd want to swim in that, especially after scrubbing.

Comment: @isherwood, yes under this proposed treatment I'd still drain, scrub and wet-vac.

Comment: After some more reading based on this answer, I'd like to add that we need BT (as mentioned here), not BTK. So called "Mosquito Dunks" contain BT. But note: "More than 20 varieties of Bt exist. The "kurstaki" variety (Btk) is used to control caterpillars."

Comment: BT is active in alkaline stomachs ; that is insects including caterpillars. It is not active in acidic = mammal and other stomachs. My guess is the varieties are more to do with sales - "ours is better than the others".